# Tizen, как альтернатива Android - кто что думает?

Tags: android, ios

Есть такая мобильная платформа [Tizen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tizen), у которой походу есть шансы (в отличие от MeeGo и WebOS) стать чем-то сравнимым с Android и iOS. По крайней мере Samsung объявил о выпуске в этом году нескольких реальных смартфонов под управлением этой оси.

Теперь, внимание вопрос: кто-нибудь из сообщества что-нибудь слышал об этой платформе или даже уже смотрел SDK или того круче может что-то уже и писал под ним? Что думаете о перспективах данной оси?

Comment: у windows rt больше шансов =), потому у меня люмия будет следующим телефоном

Comment: вообще интересно выслушать экспертную оценку происходящего...

Comment: Люмия у меня есть, а толку то... - я не верю в WP7/8 - уже 3 года мучаются, а доля кот наплакал 2-3% - это даже не смешно.

Comment: Я думаю, после финта с тем что аппараты на 7.х не получат обновления до 8 и что ходят слухи о выходе новой операционки каждый год, еще долго не вырастет если вырастет вообще. Майкрософт все никак не может отойти от старых принципов продажи ПО, когда цикл был по 5 лет и можно было каждую версию продавать заново.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

У Самсунга сложная ситуация - они только недавно проиграли суд Эплл. И проиграли его, как они себе думают, из-за андроида. Они хотят найти виновного и андроид для этого интересная мишень. Поэтому, они решили, что если запустят свою новую ОСь, в которой исправят все, из-за чего у них патентные проблемы, то это решит все и наступит счастье. К тому же, они могут в какой то мере троллить Гугл, как ни как, но Самсунг - один с крупнейших производителей андроид устройств.

Но давайте посмотрим на список проблемных патентов. Он приведен в статье на [хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/150197/). Два патента связаны со скроллированием списков. Это известная модификация андроида от гугла, так называемые "резиновые списки", это не гугловое. Этих резиновые списки меня лично раздражают.

форма. Это также отдельная статья. Некоторые устройства от самсунг некоторым людям (особенно любителям Эппл) сильно напоминали айфоны. Возможно, это сделано умышленно, что бы перетянуть аудиторию, возможно случайно. Но опять же, к операционной системе это не имеет никакого отношения.

Лаунчер, который Самсунг ставит на свои устройства. Пользоваться им сложно (родной андроидовский мне нравится куда больше). С другой стороны он ненавязчиво копирует айфоновский.

Делаем вывод. Самсунг старается быть ближе к Эплл, но при этом не хочет винить себя. Именно по этой причине они решили сделать свою ось, которая будет "свободна от патентных обязательств". Мне кажется, это очередная мертворожденная ось.

В конце февраля в Барселоне будет очередной мобильный конгресс (MWC2013), где я буду как посетитель. На ней у Самсунга будут "семинары", куда я попаду. Вот там и будет все заметно яснее.

Мою мнение - Самсунгу нужно выпускать устройства с ванильным андроидом. Это сэкономит как время на программистах, которые делают недолаунчер, переделывают внутренности непонятно зачем, так сильно поможет пользователям. Может Самсунг с Эплл в сговоре и специально копируют? это многое прояснило.

Операционные системы, приложения для которых пишутся на javascript/html, сейчас и ближайшем будущем не взлетят. Слишком плохое соотношение быстродействие/потребление энергии.

Comment: Я бы про javascript/html еще добавил, что эту связку любят позиционировать как "написал один раз - запускай везде", только по факту это тоже не получается полностью

Comment: по факту, javascript/html годится только для программ вида "хелло ворлд", "расчет индекса веса", "просмотр статистики". Все другое можно написать, но только если кто то сядет и на с/плюсах не напишет библиотеку/компонент. Но только об этом любят умалчивать.

Но есть большой спектр бизнес приложений, где js/html - самое оно.

Comment: Проблема у Самсунга с Андроидом в том, что:

а) Они имеют бабки только за железки, а за софт бабки пилит Google. А Apple имеет и за железки и за софт

б) Google купил Моторолу с потрохами, так что если он начнет выпускать сам аппараты - то швах Самсунгу.

Я полагаю, что именно из-за этого Самсунг пытается перейти на другую ось. Да Bada не получилась, а вдруг Tizen выстрелит? Лет 5 назад кто же знал что Android так выстрелит?

Comment: а) самсунг не переживает, потому что половина зелена на яфоне от них
б) купили только изза паттентов
в) у самсунга есть еще геморой в виде смарт тв

Comment: б) купили то купили,  но они с основными игроками заключили договор, что не будут выпускать аппараты в больших количествах. Так, сотню-другую прототипов для разработчиков. Это кстати была одна с основных причин, почему им разрешили покупку.

Comment: >по факту, javascript/html годится только для программ 
>вида "хелло ворлд"
Согласен. Ситуация еще усложняется тем, что весь этот хваленый HTML5/JS конкретно подставился на гнилой истории с карточным сервисом от Apple. [Пруфлинк](http://www.sneakerheadvc.com/2012/10/15/apple-maps-proves-html5-sucks/)

Comment: >Операционные системы, приложения для которых пишутся на 
>javascript/html, сейчас и ближайшем будущем не взлетят. 
>Слишком плохое соотношение быстродействие/потребление энергии.

Тем более что Facebook полностью [переписал свой код для iOS с html5 на нативное](http://www.macrumors.com/2012/06/27/facebook-abandoning-html5-to-speed-up-ios-app/) - вполне возможно что это сигнал к началу конца html5

Comment: И для андроид же тоже переписал с вебвью или ошибаюсь? SDK нынче у них вообще другой.

Comment: Под андроид не знаю, а под айось его сдк прмо летать стал после переписывания, так что это отличный аргумент в споре против html5 программ

Answer (score 8):

Сразу возникает вопрос: а зачем? Непонятно немного почему сие чудо должно взлететь?
Это напоминает просто тренд какой-то: ты еще не запилил свою мобильную ОС? Тогда мы идем к тебе!

Ну серьезно, финские парни там во всю трудятся, Mozilla скоро девайсы представит, BlackBerry 10 вот вот и еще Тизен. Успевай угнаться за ними:)

По мне так, это перебор. Хочется уже что-то одно, чтобы не распыляться.

Как я понимаю, тут снова js в основе. Мдаа...нативные апи...игры...называется ждем будущего когда веб будет гигабитным повсемирно, а вебкит таким же по скорости как нативные приложения.

На хабре было упоминаение про эту ос.
Честно говоря если взлетит, то будет интересно, но мне кажется врят ли, по крайней мере в ближайшие 2-3 года. Хотя кто его знает. В сознании людей только сформировалось, что ios - это круто, а андроид - ничем не хуже и даже лучше в некоторых моментах. И тут на рынок выйдут новые ос и пока к тому же дойдут до нас, до масс пройдет много времени. На первых порах покупать будут только гики. Если большинство вендоров поддержит Тизен, то может быть дела пойдут быстрее и выстрелит. Но это вопрос и процесс рандомный.

Попробовать написать что-то можно, но всерьез воспринимать думаю рановато.

Посмотрел их доку: IDE есть(Eclipse c плагинами для js, c++, графический дизайнер аля андроидовский), да js и весь веб-стек в основе api - Welcome Web Developers :) Выглядит интересно - написать, покопать SDK ради фана попробую:) Посмотрим! Интересное нынче время.

Comment: Да, в этом и проблема: хочешь быть "в струе" успевай только осваивать новые SDK. С Андроидом скоро я чую будет как и с PHP - начнут писать все кому не лень и убьют платформу.

Comment: Ну да, количество "адекватных" вопросов даже на данном форуме тому показатель. Печально. С другой стороны опытные разработчики могут сосредоточиться на качестве, хороших библиотеках, упрощающих жизнь, возможно покорение игровых консолей вроде Ouya(название там сложное) или смарт-тв, который правда сыроват.

Comment: Ещё один аспект, затрудняющий переход на новую ОС - приложения. На Андроиде есть приложения на любой вкус. А кто-нибудь что-нибудь сейчас пишет под Tizen? Пока под Tizen не будет достаточно приложений, никто не будет на неё переходить. А пока у Tizen будет мало пользователей, никто не станет писать под него приложения. Такой вот замкнутый круг.

Comment: Это так, но самсунгу не составит сложностей набрать армию программеров(не будем называть каких) и напилить клиенты под соц сети, почту и кучу предустановленного софта. Другой вопрос: кому она(ОС) нужна, ибо есть андроид во всех категориях ценовых.

Answer (score 3):

Очередная реинкарнация maemo, moblin, limo, mego, и т.д. На мой скромный взгляд, даже Ubuntu для смартфонов смотрится более перспективно. У Samsung денег полно, они могут эксперементировать, может и на FireFoxOS выпустят девайс, два, это ни о чем не говорит. Возможно они Tizen рассматривают как замену своей уже умирающей Bada, и пока Google не будет сильно навязывать свое мнение в производстве смартов на Android, Samsung не станет сам выпускать Tizen-конкурентов своим Android-флагманам.

Comment: Ubuntu для смартфонов это deface Androida...

Answer (score 3):

> По крайней мере Samsung объявил о
> выпуске в этом году нескольких
> реальных смартфонов под управлением
> этой оси.

Ну да, а до этого он выпустил несколько смартфонов на баде и где она сейчас? HP тоже успел что-то наклепать на вебоси, а нокия на мегу-маемо, вопрос аналогичный. Больше похоже на подстраховку - типа если что-то не так будет с андроидом, у нас есть своя ось, даже две